Pytest - Test passes when ran individually but not all together using pytest -s
this method
def test_clear(self):  
    url = self._api("progress?_=123&__=456")
    import time
    time.sleep(60)
    print(url)
    response_out = requests.get(url)
    response_out.raise_for_status()

fails when ran using pytest -s with error - HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http://127.0.0.1:54583/gather/progress?_=123&__=456, but passes when called using pytest -s filename.py

500 is a server error. So look at the server what is wrong.

But it passes when ran individually

How relevant are separate tests? Is your service guaranteed to be called separately? I guess not.
